# Best way to schedule one-time events in serverless environments

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks, serverless

### Example use case

Send the user a notification 2 hours after signup.

### Options considered

`setTimeout(() => { /* send notification */ }, 2*60*60*1000);` is not an option in serverless environments since the function terminates after execution (so it has to be stateless).

CloudWatch events can schedule lambda invocations using cron expressions - but this was designed for repetitive invocations (there's a limit of 100 rules/region).

I have not seen scheduling options in AWS SNS/SQS or GCP Pub/Sub. Are there alternatives with scheduling?

I want to avoid (if possible) setting up a dedicated message broker (overkill) or stateful/non-serverless instance - is there a serverless way to do this?

I can queue the events in a database and invoke a lambda function every minute to poll the database for events to execute in that minute... is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Look into Google Cloud Tasks.

Comment: @DougStevenson Google Cloud Tasks looks ideal for this - thanks! I will try it.

Answer (score 3):

Use AWS Step functions, they are like serverless functions that don't have the 15 minute limit like AWS Lambda does.  You can design a workflow in AWS step that integrates with API Gateway, Lambda and SNS to send email and text notifications as follows:

1. Create a REST API via API gateway that will invoke a Lambda function passing in for example, the destination address (email, phone #) of the SNS notification, when it should be sent, notification method (e.g. email, text, etc.).
2. The Lambda function on invocation will invoke the Step function passing in the data (Lambda is needed because API Gateway currently can't invoke Step functions directly).
3. The Step function is basically a workflow, you can define states for waiting (like waiting for the specified time to send the notification e.g. 30 seconds), and states for invoking other Lambda functions that can use SNS to send out an email and/or text notifications.

A [rudimentary example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/task-timer-sample.html) is provided by AWS w/ their Task Timer example.

Answer (score 0):

Things are coming on GCP for doing this, but not very soon. Thereby, today, the solution is to poll a database.

You can to that with Datastore/firestore with the execution datetime indexed (to prevent to read all the documents each minute). But be careful of traffic spike, you could create hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloud Scheduler on Google Cloud Platform. As is is stated in the official documentation :

> Cloud Scheduler is a fully managed enterprise-grade cron job scheduler. It allows you to schedule virtually any job, including batch, big data jobs, cloud infrastructure operations, and more. You can automate everything, including retries in case of failure to reduce manual toil and intervention. Cloud Scheduler even acts as a single pane of glass, allowing you to manage all your automation tasks from one place.

Here you can check a [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub) for using it with Pub/Sub and Cloud Functions.

Comment: Google Cloud Scheduler looks similar to CloudWatch Events - it's designed for repetitive/cron jobs - there's a [250 job limit](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/quotas).

Comment: In case your invocations should not be repetitive, you can also check Cloud Tasks : https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview